# NuGet package manager cannot find recently pushed packages (for a period of time)

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have used a couple of Nuget servers now, such as https://github.com/sunsided/docker-nuget and more recently the Github package manager.

With each, I regularly run into the same problem - I will push a new package, update the package references in my .csproj files and then try to build the project (which should automatically restore packages in VS) or run `dotnet restore` manually. I'll often see the message:

```
Unable to fund package Example.Project with version (>= 1.2.3)
```

I've tried clearing the cache like:

```
Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings > General > Clear All NuGet Cache(s)
```

But still the new package version is not found.

Invariably, waiting some indeterminate amount of time seems to resolve the issue, but waiting is frustrating.

Is there another cache that I'm unaware of or does anybody have a work around for this?

Comment: Seems like ```dotnet restore --no-cache``` may have done the trick, will update later to confirm if this is consistent. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before building in Visual studio, run the following from a shell from one of the project folders (where .csproj file is located):

```
dotnet restore --no-cache
```